# Makefile for C Program

Tags: c, makefile

I am trying to use this Makefile for a C Program. Could you please share with me a way how I can understand the Make utility better? I am trying the following:

```
# stack/Makefile
CC := gcc
CFLAGS += -std=c99
CFLAGS += -Wall
CFLAGS += -Wextra
CFLAGS += -g
VPATH = main src

all: bin/main.exe clean run
bin/main.exe: bin/main.o bin/stack.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)
bin/main.o: main.c
bin/stack.o: stack.c stack.h
bin/%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
demo:       
    ../bin/main.exe
clean:
    rm -f bin/*.o 
run:
    bin/main.exe
.PHONY: all clean run
```

And I getting this message:

```
gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -g -c -o bin/main.o main.c
error: unable to open output file 'bin/main.o': 'No such file or directory'
1 error generated.
make: *** [bin/main.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Do you have a sub-directory `bin` yet?  If not, create it and rerun the `make` command.

Comment: Yes the subdirectory is in place: `ls
bin     main    src     test`

Comment: Hold on; if the source file `main.c` is in `src`, but the compiler finds it as `main.c`, then the object file should go into `../bin/main.o`, not `bin/main.o`.  You have a `bin` directory at the top-level, but your commands are being run down one level, and you therefore need to go up (`..`) before you go down to the `bin` directory.  Is that that problem?

Comment: The main file is in the main folder not in the src folder. Sorry :-S

Comment: OK; then what is the `ls` showing?  Please update the question with the extra information — it's not possible to do much formatting in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

The error stems from the fact that your Makefile wants to
generate the executable and object files in subdirectory `bin` but it
contains no rule to ensure that `bin` exists when it is
needed. As @JonathanLeffler comments, you can solve that
just by manually creating `bin` yourself.

But it is often desired that a Makefile itself will ensure
that a subdirectory, or some other resource, exists when it
is needed, and you probably assumed that the pattern-rule

```
bin/%.o: %.c
```

would create `bin` as needed. It won't.

Your Makefile can ensure the existence of `bin` if you
amend it like this:

Somewhere below the `all` rule, add a new target:

```
bin:
    mkdir -p $@
```

This is to make the `bin` subdirectory if it doesn't exist.

Then change the rule:

```
bin/%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

to:

```
bin/%.o: %.c | bin
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

The additional `| bin` is an example of an [order-only prequisite](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html)
It means: If any of the targets (the `bin/%.o` things) needs to be remade from any of preceding prequisites (the ones before `|`, i.e. the `%.c`
things), then `bin` must be made first. So, as soon as anything needs to be made in `bin`, `bin` will be made first.

There is another more basic flaw in your Makefile. `all` is dependent on `clean`, so every time you successfully build
your program the object files are deleted. I understand that you *intend* this, but it entirely
defeats the purpose of `make`, which is to *avoid the need to rebuild everything* (object files, executables) every
time by instead just rebuilding those things that have become out-of-date with respect to their prerequisites.

So `all` should not depend on `clean`, and then an object file will be recompiled only if it *needs* to
be recompiled, i.e. is older than the corresponding source file. If and when you want to clean out the
object files, run `make clean`.

Finally, your `demo` rule:

```
demo:       
    ../bin/main.exe
```

is inconsistent with the others. The others assume that the `bin` where the executable
is put is in the current directory. The `demo` rule assumes it is in the *parent* of
the current directory. If you correct the `demo` rule then it will be identical to
the `run` rule, so it is superfluous, but if it were not superfluous then it should
be added it to the `.PHONY` targets.

Answer (score -1):

The best way to learn the proper way to use makefiles is to read the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html).  Also, you can Google for some [simple tutorials](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#safe=off&q=make%20tutorial).

Comment: Unless you have a specific tutorial in mind, I don't think "google it" is a very good answer.

Comment: RTFM is the answer, googling for it is just an additional bonus comment.